# Vmware Install Error - vmwarer mcisocket64.msi failed

Tags: vmware-player

The following error is achieved on Vmware Installation when installing on an x64 Windows 7:

vmware
mcisocket64.msi failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why... but in looking at the vmsetup.20120104134836.log within %TEMP% I noted:

```
20120104134909:INFO    CPackageManager::GetFile: VMwareVmciSockets64.msi
20120104134909:INFO    CMSIHelper::InitMsiParameters: MSI Parameters: 
20120104134909:INFO    CMSIHelper::InitMsiLogging: Successfully enabled logging to file C:\Users\dan\AppData\Local\Temp\vmsetup.20120104134836.vmwarevmcisockets64.msi.install.log, with mode 7967
20120104134909:INFO    CInstallMSIOperation::Execute: Preparing to install VMwareVmciSockets64.msi, options: uninstall_on_rollback: 1, use_internal_ui: 0, parameters: 
20120104134916:INFO    CInstallMSIOperation::Execute: Finished installing msi [0]
20120104134916:INFO    CBootstrapCmd::RunOperation: Operation 'InstallMSI' completed successfully with return code 65537
```

There is no user "dan" on my machine, so the above path would not work. I do not know why Vmware was looking for Dan... as far as I know Dan has never used my machine, and there is no reference in the registry to a "Dan".

However, creating the directory where it was trying to create the file allowed the installation to finish without an issue.

Hopefully this ends up helping someone else out as well.

Comment: This worked. I had to make folder : C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\vmware_1338547376\ for example